# How to separate values from 1 column in to 2 separate columns where count is more than 1 . Dont want row value to be in column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data in this format

```
Cust_ID    Order_Bname
----------------------
  1          Samsung
  1          Apple
  1          pixel
  2          Apple
  3          pixel
  3          LG
```

I want output in this format:

```
Cust_ID     Order_Bname1    order_Bname2    Order_Bname3
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1           Samsung            Apple         Pixel
 2           Apple              Null          Null
 3           Pixel              LG            null
```

Basically I want single row for each customer.

I have tried `FOR XML PATH` like this

```
SELECT Cust_ID + ',' + Order_Bname 
FROM temp1
FOR XML PATH ('')
```

This returns output in this format

```
Cust_ID      Order
---------------------------------
 1           Apple,Samsung,Pixel
 2           apple
 3           pixel,LG
```

Is there a way to achieve this? I am not able to figure out how

Update 2:

```
WITH CTE_count
as
(
  select Customer_ID as ID,Brand_Name +'-'+ cast([Sale_Amount] as nvarchar) 
  as 
  brandname,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY Customer_ID)
  AS lineNumber
  from dbo.sheet1
  group by Customer_ID,Brand_Name,[Sale_Amount]
)
 SELECT ID, brandname,lineNumber
 FROM CTE_count
```

using this I have got this format:

[image]

Now how do I create column dynamically from row number and put brand name in to them

Comment: I dont want my row value in column name hence not a pivot question

Comment: Priyal, I can't write an answer on a closed question, but you need to start by creating a RowNo partitioned by ID in a subquery. This way you know what column each row should be in. Then group by ID for the main query, and join back to the subquery once for each Order1, order2 column to get the column data.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51201359/is-it-possible-to-convert-rows-to-a-variable-number-of-columns-in-t-sql for a similar example

Comment: @DancingFool i did this part   
 `SELECT Customer_ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 
  Customer_ID ORDER BY Customer_ID)
   AS lineNumber FROM dbo.Sheet1`   I didnt got the next part you said

Comment: @DancingFool i have updated the question with your suggestion.Please help how do i move forward

Comment: If you look at the link I gave you, there is an example there that is very similar. It was doing multiple groupings, but the theory is the same.